# Remove the redundant black background in the footer

Tags: html, css

I have a html page, the background is black. The main interface is kind of red. Please see the image.
[image: web]

Please ignore the asian fonts if you don't know(embeded in the images). You can see there are a lot of black parts under red part also on the left and right.

I really don't know why it caused it.

The entire html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title><style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>


<body bgcolor="#000000">
<!-- ImageReady Slices () -->
<div align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="815">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="1" width="349"></td>
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="1" width="77"></td>
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="1" width="56"></td>
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="1" width="106"></td>
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="1" width="227"></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="5" height="116"> <img src="http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/6433/test01.gif" alt="" usemap="#Map4" border="0" height="116" width="815"></td>
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="116" width="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="left" bgcolor="#b52904" valign="top">
    <div align="center">
      <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" height="140" width="400">
        <param name="movie" value="Artwork/mainalbum.swf">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
    <embed src="Artwork/main.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="140" width="400"></object>
    </div></td>
  <td colspan="3" rowspan="2"> <img src="http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/7442/test03.gif" alt="" usemap="#Map3" border="0" height="217" width="389"></td>
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="140" width="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"> <img src="http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/2240/test04.gif" alt="" height="109" width="426"></td>
  <td height="77"> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="77" width="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" height="32"> <img src="http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/579/test05.gif" alt="" usemap="#Map2" border="0" height="32" width="162"></td>

  <td rowspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#b52904" valign="top"><p><font color="#ffffff"><strong>News:</strong></font></p>


      <p><a href="cn/church_life.html">- Church life albums </a></p>
      <p><a href="cn/res_sermons.html">Sermon</a></p>
      </td>
      <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="32" width="1"></td>
     </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" bgcolor="#b52904" valign="top"> <img src="http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/9735/test07.gif" alt="" height="135" width="349"></td>
        <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"> <img src="http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/4696/test08.gif" alt="" usemap="#Map" border="0" height="53" width="133"></td>
       <td rowspan="3" bgcolor="#b52904">&nbsp; </td>
       <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="53" width="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#b52904"><img src="http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/743/test10w.gif" height="82" width="133">
     </td>
     <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="80" width="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="2"> <img src="http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/6978/test11m.gif" alt="" height="2" width="227"></td>
    <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="2" width="1"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <!-- End ImageReady Slices -->
    </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `bgcolor="#000000"` on `<body>` to get rid of the black background.

Comment: It does remove the black but the white part is coming. Not working. I want the red main part fits the entire screen.

Comment: If you want the background to be red, then change it to `<body bgcolor="#b52904">`

Comment: The main part is a table. I want to the table fit the screen. Is the size of the table is too small?

Comment: Yes, if you want the table to fit the whole screen, then you need to use CSS: `table { width: 100%; }`. You may have to modify the contents of the table similarly.

Answer (score 0):

To change the table width, set it to 100%:

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title></title><style type="text/css"> 

</style> 
</head> 


<body bgcolor="#000000"> 
<!-- ImageReady Slices () --> 
<div align="center"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
  <tbody><tr> 
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="1" width="349"></td> 
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="1" width="77"></td> 
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="1" width="56"></td> 
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="1" width="106"></td> 
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="1" width="227"></td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
  <td colspan="5" height="116"> <img src="http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/6433/test01.gif" alt="" usemap="#Map4" border="0" height="116" width="815"></td> 
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="116" width="1"></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
  <td colspan="2" align="left" bgcolor="#b52904" valign="top"> 
    <div align="center"> 
      <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" height="140" width="400"> 
        <param name="movie" value="Artwork/mainalbum.swf"> 
        <param name="quality" value="high"> 
    <embed src="Artwork/main.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="140" width="400"></object> 
    </div></td> 
  <td colspan="3" rowspan="2"> <img src="http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/7442/test03.gif" alt="" usemap="#Map3" border="0" height="217" width="389"></td> 
  <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="140" width="1"></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"> <img src="http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/2240/test04.gif" alt="" height="109" width="426"></td> 
  <td height="77"> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="77" width="1"></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
  <td colspan="2" height="32"> <img src="http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/579/test05.gif" alt="" usemap="#Map2" border="0" height="32" width="162"></td> 

  <td rowspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#b52904" valign="top"><p><font color="#ffffff"><strong>News:</strong></font></p> 


      <p><a href="cn/church_life.html">- Church life albums </a></p> 
      <p><a href="cn/res_sermons.html">Sermon</a></p> 
      </td> 
      <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="32" width="1"></td> 
     </tr> 
        <tr> 
        <td rowspan="3" bgcolor="#b52904" valign="top"> <img src="http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/9735/test07.gif" alt="" height="135" width="349"></td> 
        <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"> <img src="http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/4696/test08.gif" alt="" usemap="#Map" border="0" height="53" width="133"></td> 
       <td rowspan="3" bgcolor="#b52904">&nbsp; </td> 
       <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="53" width="1"></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
     <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#b52904"><img src="http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/743/test10w.gif" height="82" width="133"> 
     </td> 
     <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="80" width="1"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td height="2"> <img src="http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/6978/test11m.gif" alt="" height="2" width="227"></td> 
    <td> <img src="http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9060/spacerusa.gif" alt="" height="2" width="1"></td> 
    </tr> 
    </tbody></table> 
    <!-- End ImageReady Slices --> 
    </div> 

   </body> 
   </html>
```

Comment: SWF is only a part of the page. You misunderstood it.